# Can we use queryParams in ionic4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

We have used `queryParams` for angular projects. can we use `queryParams` in ionic project?
is there any side effect or security issues?

Comment: anyhow you are using Angular Router in Ionic 4, so it will be same as Angular in Ionic 4 if you meant for Routing Query Parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.router.navigate(['your-page-name-here'], params);

Answer (score 1):

You can use queryParams but it is not a recommended way because you are sending values as a part of router link. This also means that you are limited to strings only and objects need to be stringified (JSON.stringify()) and parsed each time you send data.

Better option is to **use Extras State**:

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        userData: this.user
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(['my-page'], navigationExtras);
```

In MyPage, get data from the State by injecting Router in constructor:

```
this.data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.userData;
```

**Using Service:** Also, you can create a service that has a getter and setter that you can use to save data in it before navigating and retrieve it after completing the navigation:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private data = [];

  constructor() { }

  setData(id, data) {
    this.data[id] = data;
  }

  getData(id) {
    return this.data[id];
  }
}
```